# NUnit Framework AssertionException with no clear reason why

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Per my code below. I'm testing UI to ensure correct permissions for a application are applied to certain user accounts.

When I run the below, the test passes at "Assert.Pass(); //marks as a pass here ok".
Following this, code drops into the catch block.

The exception message is literally blank, the stack trace is:

> at NUnit.Framework.Assert.Pass(String message, Object[] args)    at
> NUnit.Framework.Assert.Pass()    at
> SigangeCoreUiTests.Tests.PermissionTests.BslUserPermissionTest() in
> C:...\PermissionTests.cs:line 90

The test then obviously fails because of the assert fail, however there is no reason for the exception to be raised and it already passed. The screen shot capture is not raising an issue, it seems to be the Assert.Pass.

Why might my code do this?

```
 public void BslUserPermissionTest()
    {
        var _testUsername = _configuration.GetValue<string>("PermissionsTestUserList:BSLUser:Username");
        var _testPassword = _configuration.GetValue<string>("PermissionsTestUserList:BSLUser:Password");
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));

        try
        {
            if (!LoginHandler(_testUsername, _testPassword))
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var menuItem = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText("BSL Interpreter")));
            menuItem.Click();

            var result = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("app-bsl-interpreter")));

            if (result.Text.Contains("Message for Interpretation"))
            {
                //test no other menu items are present - only expecting the one menu item
                if (ValidateSingleMenuItemPresent())
                {
                    new SupportClasses.ScreenShot().Take(_driver, false);
                    Assert.Fail();
                }

                new SupportClasses.ScreenShot().Take(_driver, true);
                Assert.Pass(); //marks as a pass here ok
            }
            else
            {
                new SupportClasses.ScreenShot().Take(_driver, false);
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //raises exception for unknown reason
        {
           new SupportClasses.ScreenShot().Take(_driver, false);
           Assert.Fail(); 
        }
        finally
        {
            _driver = new SupportClasses.SsdAuthentiation(_driver).Logout();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assert.Pass` throws exception, you should use Assert to check values as per your test case.

See the below code from [GitHub](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Assert.cs#L105).

```
    /// <summary>

    /// Throws a <see cref="SuccessException"/> with the message and arguments

    /// that are passed in. This allows a test to be cut short, with a result

    /// of success returned to NUnit.

    /// </summary>

    [DoesNotReturn]

    static public void Pass()

    {

        Assert.Pass(string.Empty, null);

    }
```

Comment: The answer is correct. Supplementing it... in modern NUnit versions, you should not try to catch the exceptions thrown by NUnit to indicate Success, Failure, etc. In older versions, you could do this and even change the result but it has not been true for some time.

Comment: @Charlie you’re right